# T-Nuts for Granite/Plywood table?

Tags: furniture, carpentry, plywood

I have a 30"x50"x3/4" granite slab that I would like to use for a table. I'm thinking of putting 5/8" plywood underneath (20"x40"?) and before mounting the granite on top, inserting a few T-Nuts for this type of legs: https://www.homedepot.ca/product/live-edge-timber-co--38-inch-high-x-19-inch-wide-steel-furniture-legs-pair-of-2/1001215038

1. Are t-nuts my best option, or is there some thing else I should consider?
2. Is 5/8 plywood thick enough?
3. Anything to consider when cutting the plywood size, aside from wide enough for the legs, not wider than granite?

Comment: Plywood  is not the same as very thick live edge slab . Without any type of bracing to stop racking i think the plywood would start to de-laminate over time if racking occurs. How about a hardwood or cross bracing on the back side corner to corner between legs ?

Comment: I figured the slab would provide enough support so it won't rack. Would 1" hardwood be better or thicker?

Comment: "*I figured the slab would provide enough support so it won't rack*" You said you were using plywood not a slab. I referenced a slab because the legs are marketed for use with a slab on the HD link you provided.  1" hardwood would be better then plywood. Without bracing or securing it to a wall you will get some racking, racking over time can weaken connections.

Comment: Legs attached to the plywood, plywood glued to the granite slab.

Comment: If I was building this, I'd figure out something that functioned like an apron or brackets between the legs to keep them from folding. If you wanted to get complicated, large steel plates could be routed into the ply, and the legs attached to them (probably through tapped holes).

Comment: Thanks, seems general consensus is that it won't be sturdy enough. I might look for an old iron table or build a base out of wood.

Answer (score -1):

I have a 36" X 68" kitchen island top of 3/4 granite . It simply rests on the frame work of the island, basically 3/4 plywood on edge with cabinets and drawers like typical kitchen cabinets. There are some cross members of 2" wide 3/4 plywood. The granite is loose and can be moved. I was going to do something more sturdy but have not gotten to it in 25 years. I have stood on it a few times , I keep my feet over the 3/4 on edge plywood. A good finish carpenter made the island so it is very flat. So cabinet type birch plywood should be enough.

Comment: I apologize for downvoting, but this answer doesn't address the attachment of the legs.

Comment: I guess I focused on "plywood glued to granite".